# oracle intersect doesn't work

Tags: sql, oracle

In the Oracle SQL, why this code doesn't compile? Oracle doesn't support intersect? intersect only takes one column value?

assume two table have same column types.

Thanks

```
select B.name, B.id from tmp_B B where B.id in (select distinct id from tmp_A);
intersect
select distinct A.name, A.id from tmp_A A;
```

error message

```
Error report:
Unknown Command
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a syntax error in your statement.  You have an extra semicolon after the initial `SELECT` and before the `INTERSECT`.

```
select B.name, B.id from tmp_B B where B.id in (select distinct id from tmp_A)
intersect
select distinct A.name, A.id from tmp_A A
```

should be a valid SQL statement assuming that `ID` and `NAME` have the same data types in both tables.